# How do I make a certain portion of a regular expression optional?

Tags: regex

How do I make certain portion of a regular expression optional? For example:

```
\d* [\\s\\w*?]
```

...where the expression inside the brackets is optional.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's quite the regular expression you want. [\s\w*?] says "match one character that is a space, a word, a star, or a question mark".  I think you ultimately what you want is (\s\w)*? which says "match 0 or more of a space followed by a word and don't be greedy about it.

Though you could be looking for (\s|\w)*? which says "match a word or a space 0 or more times and don't be greedy about it."

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `*` after the `]`. `*` means 0 or more.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a bracketed group optional, so `(abc)?` would work as expected. `\d*(\s\w*?)?` I think would do what you're describing

Answer (score 0):

Add `?` after the `]`. The `?` means zero or one of the preceding element.